# Data compression from lack of patterns

Tags: algorithms, data-analysis

From my understanding, lossless data compression takes advantages of statistical patterns. I want to know if it is possible to compress data based on the lack of patterns, such as a random string of digits (like the kind you would find in the digits of $\pi$). The saved space comes from the complete lack of any pattern, which itself is unique. If it has already been done, I would like to know if there are any notable implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively, this might sound plausible, but, in fact, there are sooooo many more ways of being unpatterned than of being patterned that there's no way to abbreviate it *losslessly*.

But, if we pursue the aspect that much of the "patternless" aspect of photos and such is irrelevant to human visual perception (for example), then we can find *lossy* things like JPEG that "lose lots of information", but, hopefully, the huge amount of "information" that is lost is *irrelevant*. Just noise.

So, short summary, if all the details of the chaotic info *matter*, it's a problem, because you probably can't compress it. But if, for your purposes, the "random" parts are also the "irrelevant" parts, then various lossy schemes (JPEG being historically one of the first, I think) can be very good.

Comment: Would it be right to assume with a file full of digits the data isn't really random? (because there's only 10 digits and 128 ASCII) I know algorithms like DEFLATE can get a 60% compression ratio on a file of random digits.

Comment: @qwr, yes, indeed, a file full of any restricted alphabet will be compressible for reasons as you observe.